# Pegar um label por parent() ou por id e fazer replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código de OpenCart em twig.

```
{% for quote in shipping_method.quote %}
<div class="radio">
  <label id="{{quote.code}}"> {% if quote.code == code or not code %}
    {% set code = quote.code %}
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="{{ quote.code }}" checked="checked" />
    {% else %}
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="{{ quote.code }}" />
    {% endif %}
    {{ quote.title }} - {{ quote.text }}</label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Onde eu recebo um valor `{{quote.text}}` e preciso removê-lo, mas não é para todo o for. Apenas quando esse valor é R$0,00; esse meu `ID` da `label` é definido por `id="flat.flat"`

Depois de renderizado ele fica assim:

```
<label id="flat.flat">     
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="flat.flat">
        Frete para outras regiões, entrar em contato - R$0,00
</label>
```

O que eu tentei fazer em jQuery e ficou da seguinte maneira

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var auxiliar = $('#flat.flat').text();
    console.log(auxiliar);
    auxiliar = auxiliar.replace('- R$0,00','');
    console.log(auxiliar);
    $("#flat.flat").html(auxiliar);
  });

</script>
```

Mas ele não retorna nada no console.
O que eu preciso mudar para que ele funcione?

Comment: Infelizmente, não conheço essa sintaxe de renderização, mas uma coisa imagino a respeito: ela tem renderização condicional? Diga-me o nome dessa engine, por favor, talvez, eu possa lhe ajudar.

Comment: Esqueci de passar, uso Opencart e o arquivo é twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme a documentação do [`Twig`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/if.html), usando o fluxo de controle `if`, tenta o seguinte:

```
{% if quote.text == "0,00" %}
  {{ quote.title }}</label>
{% else %}
   {{ quote.title }} - {{ quote.text }}</label>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simulei um pequeno exemplo baseado no seu modelo, veja se te ajuda:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const listaParaReplace = $('.identificador-replace');
    for (i = 0; i < listaParaReplace.length; i++) {
        var auxiliar = $(listaParaReplace[i]).html();
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log(auxiliar);
        auxiliar = auxiliar.replace('- R$0,00','');
        console.log(auxiliar);
        $(listaParaReplace[i]).html(auxiliar);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label id="1">
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <span class="identificador-replace">"quote.title - 1" - "quote.text - 1: - R$0,00"</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label id="2">
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2" />
    <span class="identificador-replace">"quote.title - 2" - "quote.text - 2: - R$20,00"</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label id="3">
    <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="3" />
    <span class="identificador-replace">"quote.title - 3" - "quote.text - 3: - R$0,00"</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou também, mas o apenas com twig é melhor. Esqueci que poderia usar ela para retirar essa parte do texto.